# %matplotlib inline not working with axes

Tags: matplotlib, ipython

in IPython if I use the following code, I can see the plot inline:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
```

but if I use this code, the graph does not appear inline or in separate window:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
```

I am running Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| on Windows 7 
matplotlib version is 1.5.1

Comment: Rare. Add the version of python, python and matplotlib to the question

Comment: @lbellomo I am running Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| on Windows 7 
matplotlib version is 1.5.1

Comment: @lbellomo any suggestions?

Comment: Try updating. It looks like a Bug, if you continue you should report it.